# How to import fundamental data from TWS via IBAPI using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to request stock fundamental data (e.g. financial statements) from TWS using reqFundamentalData() method of the Eclient class but was unsuccessful.

I am new to IBAPI and have been trying to import stock fundamental data from TWS using Python. I am sure the connection is successful as I can request ContractDetails from the application. But then somehow the reqfundamentaldata() method is just not working.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper


class MyWrapper(EWrapper):

    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        print("setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        # start program here or use threading
        app.reqContractDetails(4444, contract)
        app.reqFundamentalData(4444, contract, "ReportsFinSummary", [])

def contractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
    print(reqId, contractDetails.contract)# my version doesnt use summary

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId):
         print("ContractDetailsEnd. ", reqId)
         # this is the logical end of your program
         app.disconnect() 

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
         print("Error. Id: " , reqId, " Code: " , errorCode , " Msg: " , 
         errorString)


 wrapper = MyWrapper()
 app = EClient(wrapper)
 app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, clientId=123)
  print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % (app.serverVersion(), 
  app.twsConnectionTime()))

  from ibapi.contract import Contract
  contract = Contract()
  contract.symbol = "IBKR"
  contract.secType = "STK"
  contract.currency = "USD"
  contract.exchange = "ISLAND"

  app.run()
```

Results:
serverVersion:148 connectionTime:b'20190203 09:03:21 HKT'
setting nextValidOrderId: %d 1
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2104  Msg:  Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2104  Msg:  Market data farm connection is OK:hfarm
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2104  Msg:  Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2106  Msg:  HMDS data farm connection is OK:hkhmds
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2106  Msg:  HMDS data farm connection is OK:fundfarm
Error. Id:  -1  Code:  2106  Msg:  HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
4444 43645865,IBKR,STK,,0.0,,,ISLAND,IEX,USD,IBKR,IBKR,False,,combo:
ContractDetailsEnd.  4444

Process finished with exit code 0